# Python, How to make single connection to a server from another server?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, python-requests

For instance, a web server (Django/flask) would talk to Elasticsearch server.

I find the following code, and think `requests.session()` gives me the `connection reuse` (Am I right on this?)

```
class ElasticSearch(object):
    self.session = requests.session()
    ...
```

Whenever I want to talk to Elasticsearch, I do the following

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
```

Wouldn't it create a requests.session object, so I'm creating `requests.session` object *(thus separate connection)* for each module I declare `Elasticsearch()` ?

What happens if I instantiate `Elasticsearch()` inside a function / method?
Since the `Elasticsearch()` and it's `self.session` is recreated every function call, I get no connection reuse?

```
def get_something_from_es(self):
    from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
    es = Elasticsearch()
```

Should I create a singleton for `Elasticsearch()` if I want to use only 1 connection?

Why do I not see such code often? *(I google elasticsearch singleton, comes up almost nothing)* It's not a good idea to share the connection?

well, I guess it might be worth a standalone question, but I'm interested in knowing the best practices using `requests library` for server to server connection.

1. I'm sure elasticsearch-py has the answer to the question *(because they have the implementation)*.
2. Although they have the answer to the first question, I 'm not sure I'm using it correctly *(This question is more about this)*

Comment: sessions are fairly ephemeral things. I wouldn't worry too much about creating extras.

Comment: Are you implying, doing `session = requests.Session() ` multiple times has nothing to do with connection reuse?

Comment: no, only that I'm not sure why you're concerned about creating redundant sessions to Elasticsearch. You haven't presented a compelling reason that one might _care_ about the redundant sessions.

Comment: Oh, my reasoning was like, if session hold the connection object and if we want to reuse it, we might not recreate it.. but I may be wrong..